# Using Prolog to make a prediction based on the data in a Relational Database

Tags: sql-server, prolog, prediction, swi-prolog, expert-system

I have recently come across Prolog and I am amazed by it's powers and capability. I was wondering whether it is possible for prolog to make a prediction based on data which is in SQL Server.

Database

```
Day    Weather  Taken out Umbrella
Monday Cloudy   Yes 
Tuesday Sunny   No
Wednesday Rain   Yes 
Thursday  Sunny  No
```

Can Prolog use this data in the database and make a prediction

Comment: Prolog has no *a priori* knowledge of weather prediction but if you have some rules to derive predictions from data, you could certainly program them in prolog.  Prolog implementations usually have predicates for retrieving data from database servers via ODBC.  What have you actually tried?

Comment: @MartynA I am able to connect to the SQL Server Database using ODBC. I am also able to perform SQL Queries using Prolog.  I can make rules in my prolog file, but I am not sure how to use the data from the SQL Server database, instead of creating your own knowledge base in Prolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes-  you can train a classifier using a machine learning algorithm.
Algorithms which work well in prolog are ones that make rule models.

For example a decision tree or a rule learner such as ripper.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Artificial-Intelligence-International-Computer/dp/0321417461 chapter 18 is a good start. There is a LOT of literature on the subject ;)